# Отключить полноэкранный режим на нестандартных экранах

Tags: android

Столкнулась с такой проблемой, что на экранах нестандартного размера включается полоэкранный режим. Для меня это нежелательно. Нужно чтобы экран отображался как на скрине

[image: скрин]

Подскажите, как исправить?

При гуглении у всех вопросы наоборот как растянуть на весь экран и советуют использовать `Fullscreen`, но я этот атрибут не использую и все равно автоматически включается полноэкранный режим на телефонах размером 18*9

манифест

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

стили

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
</style>
```

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/orientation.php

Comment: Извините, в этой ссылке про ориентацию. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: В этой ссылке про ориентацию, там можно найти подробно как захардкодить  ориентацию, как узнать ориентацию и как высчитать конкретную ориентацию устройства. Что вас смущает? Или я должен был код за вас написать? Вы можете указать конкретную ориентацию для всех устройств что бы не переворачивалось, можете проверять при старте размер экрана и если вам что то не подходит устанавливать ее принудительно и так далее